# CakePHP Ajax results don't affect sql_dump details

Tags: mysql, ajax, cakephp, dump

This might be a really stupid question, but I've been banging at trying to get my sql_dump data to update when I user render for an Ajax results set..

Anyone have any idea why this is happening. Yes my debug is set to 2. And the sql_dump is just static data as of now..

Comment: Can you make it a little more clear what exactly you're doing?

Comment: I am rendering a view based on search results. The query is written into my search() action, and the results display just fine. The sql_dump is in my default layout, so its on all pages.. Does this at all help clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. My sql_dump needed to be in my ajax layout.